# Add and remove a TextView dynamically in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-framelayout, viewgroup

I have set up a FrameLayout which has a `TextView` on top of a `ListView`. Now, in the `MainActivity`, after executing some code, I check whether the `ListView` is empty. If it is, I display the `TextView`, if not, I remove the `TextView`.

The code is as follows:

Following is the **main.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add some subjects"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ItemsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In the MainActivity class, I do the following:

**MainActivity.java**

```
TextView tvNoItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddItem);
ListView subListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemsList);
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flMain);

ArrayList<Item> itemsList;

//some code

if(itemsList.isEmpty()) {
    fl.addView(tvNoItem);
} else {
    fl.removeView(tvNoItem);
}
```

Now, when I run it and I add some items to the list, the `TextView` (tvNoItem) is removed indeed. But all I see is a blank list - the list items are not visible. [BTW, the list is working fine. When I remove the `TextView` from `main.xml`, I can see all the list items.] Please help.

Comment: Why not set the view to gone? `textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: I tried that. It does the same thing. I get a blank activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `ListView`'s [emptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) option.

Here is a nice post about showing empty view while your adapter is empty. It'll be automatically shown when your Adapter's source is empty.

[Android – ListView => setEmptyView()](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-setemptyview/)

You don't need to check whether you data source (`ArrayList`) is empty, android framework will handle all the hiding and showing implementation.

Make sure to call `setEmptyView()` before you call `setAdapter()` on the `ListView`.

Answer (score 16):

```
    txtview.setVisibility(View.GONE) ;
    txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of add and remove the TextView try to hide and show it. Use for it the View.VISIBLE and VIEW.GONE properties:

```
if(itemsList.isEmpty()) {
    tvNoItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    tvNoItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: does it remove particular element from child of layout by setting its visibility to gone ?

Answer (score 1):

Before getting views dynamically in layouts reset first that

```
LinearLayout lc2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftcode1);
LinearLayout lc3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lcvalue1);

lc2.removeAllViews();
lc3.removeAllViews();
```

Above lines are worked for me to prevent duplicates dynamically adding textviews in that linear layouts

Answer (score 0):

Instead Add/Remove try to Change the Vissibility status.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a tips & tricks to show a View in when the `listView` is empty

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ViewStub
android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout="@layout/empty" />
</FrameLayout>
```

A `ViewStub` is an invisible, **zero-sized** View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime.The layout `@layout/empty` will be inflated only when the `ViewStub` visibility will change to `View.VISIBLE`. Once the `@layout/empty` view hierarchy is inflated, it replaces the `ViewStub` in the global layout.

[ViewStub documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)

[Source](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/)

Answer (score 0):

1) First, there is some problem with your code. Your `tvNoItem` is already defined in xml layout, so you shouldn't add it again. You only add views that are dynamically created, eg

```
textView tv = new TextView(this);
... //customize your text view
fl.addView(tv);
```

You really should just set your textview xml with `android:visibility="gone"` and make it visible when you want.

2) Use `LinearLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` if you want the textview on top of your listview. In your listview, change `android:layout_height="0dip"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, and remove the layout_weight.

Answer (score 0):

```
rowtxt.setText("Hello" +  ++i);//for adding textview
rltv.addView(rowtxt);

rowtxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);//use for disable textview
            rltv.removeViewAt(--i);
```